# Device can be managed but actions not available anymore in the dashboard

Tags: watson-iot

my iot devices are configured for mgmt actions, device informations get updated if required and i can see the device meta information via the dashboard, but it is not possible  to start device actions or modify device metadata via the dashboard. In the past it was possible and I suppose that this is caused by the latest dashboard refresh of Watson IOT. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the new devices action page ?

1. Open the platform and go to the `Devices` menu;
2. Click on the `Actions` sub-menu;
3. Click on the `+ Initiate Action` button on the top right;
4. In the wizard select the kind of action you want to execute and hit `Next`;
5. In the next step click on `+ Add Devices` to select the device(s) you want to execute the action. Note that only devices triggered as manageables will appear in the list;
6. Hit `Finish`.